# bigquery query repeat field

Tags: google-bigquery

I am learning the bigquery with the example: personsData
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested

in this example, there is a repeated filed called `children`. Is this possible to make a query to find out who have child called "Josh" and child call "Jim"

I tried the following query but no result return:
`select fullName from [xxx.xx] where children.name = "Jane" and children.name = "John"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong with the above query.

1. There should be an **or** not an **and** between the two criteria. e.g. children.name = "Josh" **or** children.name = "Jim"
2. If you are using the standard google data set then there is no children with the name "Josh" or "Jim"

try:

```
select fullName from PersonsData.personsdata  where children.name = "Jane" or children.name = "John"
```

with google datasets

Comment: maybe 2 subqueries, and joining the results with AND

Comment: 1. Using or won't work because it will return results contain parent who have a child called 'Josh' or 'Jim' but not both of them.
2. thanks, I will correct my question to "Jane" and  "John"